# How to get all top level window javafx?

Tags: java, javafx

I saw a method in AWT: `java.awt.Window.getWindows()`.
In JavaFx, is there any method to get all window JavaFx application?

Thanks,

Answer (score 6, accepted):

AFAIK, there is still no proper way to do this.

Although there is a **dirty and short term** way :

Browsing the [source code of `javafx.stage.Window`](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/openjfx/8/master/rt/file/16e4c07f8562/javafx-ui-common/src/javafx/stage/Window.java), there is a static method which seems to do what you are expecting : `javafx.stage.Window#impl_getWindows()`.

But there is a bunch of disclaimers :

```
/**
 * Return all Windows
 *
 * @return Iterator of all Windows
 * @treatAsPrivate implementation detail
 * @deprecated This is an internal API that is not intended for use and will be removed in the next version
 */
@Deprecated
@NoInit
public static Iterator<Window> impl_getWindows() {
    final Iterator iterator = AccessController.doPrivileged(
        new PrivilegedAction<Iterator>() {
            @Override public Iterator run() {
                return windowQueue.iterator();
            }
        }
    );
    return iterator;
}
```

Comment: That method is only list one Window JavaFX on current process. pls comment for my result?

Comment: `java.awt.Window.getWindows()` works in the way. It returns all the windows in the jre.

Comment: @gontard no it doesn't. I have a few javafx windows open but the awt.Window method still returns an empty array.

Answer (score 8):

for javafx8 running java8
use

```
FXRobotHelper.getStages()
 or 
StageHelper.getStages()
```

This will retrieve all Stages which is essentially a Window itself ( it extends Window class)

Comment: I would like to know where lies the difference by using these two methods. Thanks

Comment: Both classes are located in sub packages of com.sun.  Therefore one should not use them.  They are not stable over different Java releases and they are not even available in all Java distributions (OpenJDK).

Answer (score 5):

This has finally been fixed properly in Java 9. See [javafx.stage.Window.getWindows()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/javafx/stage/Window.html#getWindows--)

> Returns a list containing a reference to the currently showing JavaFX
>   windows. The list is unmodifiable - attempting to modify this list
>   will result in an UnsupportedOperationException being thrown at
>   runtime.

This is essential in Java 9 as the other solutions involving `StageHelper` or `FXRobotHelper` are no longer possible as these exist in `com.sun.javafx` package which can no longer be accessed.